# Where are package relations stored?

Tags: dependencies, relationship, package, enterprise-architect

I would like to measure the amount of dependencies of my EA package in other packages in the model.

I therefore loop on `t_connector` to identify the records in which elements from my package are the source, and the destinations are elements from other packages.

**All works fine with relations between elements, but relations between packages are different:**
The sub packages in my package sometimes depend on external packages in the model.  **Unfortunately, t_connector does not store this data!**
Where, then, the package relations are stored?

Comment: What do you mean by external packages?

Comment: @Uffe, External packages are other packages in the model, not withing the hierarchy of selected package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All connectors are stored in the `t_connector` table. However, the references in `t_connector.Start_Object_ID` and `t_connector.End_Object_ID` refer to `t_object.Object_ID` -- not to `t_package.Package_ID`.

In the EA data model, a UML package has a dual representation: one row in `t_package` and one in `t_object`, with `t_object.Object_Type = 'Package'` and `t_object.PDATA1 = t_package.Package_ID`. (Note that the `t_object.PDATA` columns are strings.)

So strictly speaking, only elements have connectors in EA. But the `Package` class in the API hides this and allows you to loop over the connectors of the package *element* as if they belonged to the package itself using the `Package.Connectors` collection -- but if you look at `Connector.ClientID` and `Connector.SupplierID` you'll see that neither one matches the `Package.PackageID` of the package whose connectors you're looping over.

If a connector runs from the current package to some other package, what you need to do in order to retrieve the other end of the connector is to query the repository for the *element* -- not the package -- with the connector's client ID, as in

```
connectedPackageElement = Repository.GetElementByID(connector.ClientID)
```

The good news is that the package proper and its package element both have the same name. But if you need to pull more information from the package, you'll need to issue another call like

```
connectedPackage = Repository.GetPackageByID(connectedPackageElement.MiscData(0)
```

Since you said that you were "looping over" the connectors, I've assumed you're using the API rather than issuing SQL queries. But the structures are the same; `t_object` corresponds to the `Element` class, `t_package` to the `Package` class and `t_connector` to the `Connector` class.

Comment: Thanks! Just to clarify: there is 2 options to retrive package relation information: via t_connector (inner joining to t_package). or: via package.connectors (inner joining to t_object). Correct?

Comment: No, you can't join to t_package directly. You have to go t_connector.Start/End_Object_ID => t_object.Object_ID => t_object.PDATA1 => t_package.Package_ID. And you can only do the last two if t_object.Object_Type = 'Package'.

Comment: I'm little confused: I have a package in hand. At first I get its corresponding element from t_object (using the PDATA). Then I search for t_connectors referring to this element. Makes sense?

Comment: Yes. And the other ends of those connectors also refer to t_object rows, which may or may not have Object_Type = 'Package', in which case you find the package as noted.

Answer (score 2):

They are stored in the hierarchy. t_package.parent_id links child packages to their parent. A connector is only created if you explicitly create one. If so, the connector source/target link the id of the package's element.